# Консенсус в p2p сети

Tags: python, сокет, blockchain, zeromq

Необходим консенсус в p2p системе

1. В системе 4 компьютера (далее *ноды*), общаются p2p, без общего координатора
2. клиент через браузер отправляет данные X
3. одна из 4-х нод получает эти данные
4. нода рассылает данные остальным 3 нодам и они добавляют данные от клиента каждый в свою базу, допустим под номером 7. после чего соодинение закрывается
5. если в этот момент приходит еще одни данные от другого клиента, запрос становится в очередь и пишется под номером 8 в базу каждой ноды.
6. После достижения консенсуса по записи данных под номером 7, любая из нод отправляет данные клиенту, что его данные получены и записаны в распределенную базу.

**Теперь вопрос:**
*Что лучше для этого использовать на python? Правильно ли я понял, что ZeroMQ в библиотеке pyZMQ уже давно решили эту задачу и стоит использовать этот модуль для решения такой задачи?*

Comment: классический paxos

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29#Byzantine_Paxos  - Message flow: Fast Byzantine Multi-Paxos, steady state. Получается две машины обновляют журнал, а три помогают это сделать? Если так, то тогда не работает эта система тут. Или я ошибаюсь?